# Control on Openshift Egress

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, openshift, outbound, aro

I have an openshift cluster setup in Azure (ARO) like below
[image]

Now Pod1, Pod2 and Pod3 are in 3 different namespaces.

Pod2 cannot access pod1 but If we create a route for pod1 then **pod2 is able to access the Pod1 through the route**.  which is not the ideal one for us.

Now we need to **restrict this Pod2 access to Pod1 through Pod1 Route so we decided to block through egress at Pod2**, lets say Pod1 has a domain abc.example.com then we need to block abc.example.com in Pod2 egress.

I am new to Openshift, can someone please help me in how to achieve this blocking at egress inside openshift 4.4.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have the following link aswell

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/openshift_sdn/configuring-egress-firewall.html

Comment: You should be controlling intra-cluster communication via `NetworkPolicy` objects (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/network_policy/about-network-policy.html). This is where you would allow traffic from pod2 -> pod1 _without_ the route.

Comment: @WillGordon can you please comment on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137145/network-policy-in-kubernetes-not-working-in-different-namespaces